# iMacros - How do I appened extracted data to a file?

Tags: firefox, web-scraping, imacros, data-extraction

I can use TAG..EXTRACT..SAVEAS to get a URL and write it to a file.  If I execute that 10 times in a script, the file only contains the last URL extracted - the file is being overwritten.  I don't see any documentation on how to append to an existing file.  I'd prefer to not have to give each URL it's own file name, and then join all those files from a command prompt.

iMacros for Firefox 7.6.0.2; Windows XP SP3

Comment: works fine on my side - you are doing something wrong. by default saveas will always append to existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can save diferent data without replace file with this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=ID:label-1350 EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\username\Documents\iMacros\extractions FILE=extractions.csv
```

And doesn't matter how many times you execute the macro, the file contains all the data extracted.